# Swift 2: Index out of range

Tags: arrays, button, random, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm creating a snap game with two array images, when the player matches the last element of the array I get error "Index out of range". How can I prevent this? maybe have a message that says "all cards have been matched" 
Thanks in advance

My card Arrays:

```
    var cardArray = ["angry", "apple", "boots","heart", "pumpkin", "rainbow", "sad", "acorn", "chestnuts"]
    var cardArray2 = ["enfadadoTxt", "manzanaTxt", "botasTxt", "corazonTxt", "calabazaTxt", "arcoirisTxt", "tristeTxt", "bellotaTxt", "castanaTxt"]


    @IBAction func playRoundTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    //playRoundButton.userInteractionEnabled = false

    firstRandomNumber = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextIntWithUpperBound(cardArray.count)
    firstCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: cardArray[firstRandomNumber])

    secondRandomNumber = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextIntWithUpperBound(cardArray2.count)
    secondCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: cardArray2[secondRandomNumber])



}


func getRandomIntFromArray(Array: [String]) -> Int {

    return GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextIntWithUpperBound(cardArray.count)

}
```

This is where is crashes:

```
@IBAction func snapButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    if cardArray.count > 0 {

        if firstRandomNumber == secondRandomNumber {

            self.playerScore += 1
            self.playerScoreLabel.text = String(self.playerScore)

            cardArray.removeAtIndex(firstRandomNumber)
            cardArray2.removeAtIndex(secondRandomNumber)

            firstRandomNumber = getRandomIntFromArray(cardArray)
            secondRandomNumber = getRandomIntFromArray(cardArray2)

            firstCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: cardArray[firstRandomNumber])//The problem might be here
            secondCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: cardArray2[secondRandomNumber])

            print(cardArray)
            print(cardArray2)


        } else {

            animationView.startCanvasAnimation()
            print("no match")


        }

    }

}
```

When I print firstRandom number, secondRandomNumber, array1, and array2

0
1
["angry", "pumpkin", "sad", "chestnuts"]
["enfadadoTxt", "calabazaTxt", "tristeTxt", "castanaTxt"]

1
1
["angry", "sad", "chestnuts"]
["enfadadoTxt", "tristeTxt", "castanaTxt"]

0
0
["angry", "chestnuts"]
["enfadadoTxt", "castanaTxt"]

0
0
["chestnuts"]
["castanaTxt"]

83844566
929875342
fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: What is the range of firstRandomNumber and secondRandomNumber? 0 to cardArray.count - 1?

Comment: change cardArray.count with cardArray.count - 1 and let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I can see right now is :

```
firstRandomNumber = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextIntWithUpperBound(cardArray.count)
    firstCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: cardArray[firstRandomNumber])

    secondRandomNumber = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextIntWithUpperBound(cardArray2.count)
    secondCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: cardArray2[secondRandomNumber])
```

Change it to

```
firstRandomNumber = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextIntWithUpperBound(cardArray.count - 1)
    firstCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: cardArray[firstRandomNumber])

    secondRandomNumber = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextIntWithUpperBound(cardArray2.count - 1)
    secondCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: cardArray2[secondRandomNumber])
```

also,

```
return GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextIntWithUpperBound(cardArray.count)
```

to

```
return GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextIntWithUpperBound(cardArray.count - 1)
```

My logic behind this one is that your array.count return 9 elements but array go from 0.

Comment: change it in getRandomIntFromArray as well -  return GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextIntWithUpperBound(cardArray.count - 1)

Comment: still getting same error, which is pointing to this  `firstCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: cardArray[firstRandomNumber])
                secondCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: cardArray2[secondRandomNumber])` in snap button

Comment: can you print firstRandomNumber before these lines?

Comment: well, you are trying to get 83844566 929875342  from arrays (first one is starting with 8 and the other one is from 9). Can you check what do you get for GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextIntWithUpperBound(0) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107553/discussion-between-sam-and-nickcatib).